# Identifying a curve on a closed surface of genus 4

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

The notation is the one used in the attached picture.

Take a closed, orientable surface $\Sigma_4$ of genus $4$, obtained as the identification space of a polygon with $16$ sides in the usual way. The surface has an involution $\iota \colon \Sigma_4 \to \Sigma_4$, exchanging the holes $1, \, 2$ with the holes $3, \, 4$, respectively. I also have two points $P_1$, $P_2$, switched by the symmetry. In the picture, the involution is the reflection with respect to the orange curve $c$.

Next, let us consider the closed curves $\rho_{11}, \, \rho_{12}, \, \tau_{11}, \, \tau_{12}$ in the "left half" of the surface, and their image via $\iota$, namely $\rho_{24}, \, \rho_{23}, \, \tau_{24}, \, \tau_{23}$, in the "right half"; here the subscript $ij$ means "starting from the point $P_i$ and going around the $j$th hole" as in the picture.

Now, I would like to consider the curve $\rho_{13}$, colored in cyan in the figure. This curve contains $P_1$, crosses the mirror $c$ and is disjoint from $\rho_{23}$.

> The problem is, I am unable to draw $\rho_{13}$ in the polygon model.

In fact, when I try to draw in the polygon a curve that starts and ends at $P_1$ and crosses one on the walls $\alpha_3$ or $\beta_3$, it seems to me that it intersects both $\rho_{23}$ and $\tau_{23}$. I see no way to draw such a curve so that it is disjoint from $\rho_{23}$.

I am not really an expert on $2$-dimensional topology, so I am probably missing something obvious, or I made some basic mistakes in the identification of the curves; however, I cannot see where the blunder lies. So, let me ask the

> **Question.** What is going on? Where am I wrong, and what is the correct way to identify $\rho_{13}$ in the polygon model?

[image]

**Remarks.** The [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714305/identify-a-curve-on-a-closed-surface-of-genus-4) was asked yesterday on MathSE, receiving $3$ upvotes and no answers or comments. Its research-level side concerns a research project on surface braid groups, for which I need to understand $\rho_{13}$.

Comment: Your polygon does not correspond correctly to the picture of the surface of genus 4 you have drawn. To see this, consider a small circle $L$ about the point $P_2$ and its point of intersection with the tail of the arc $\tau_{24}$. Now consider the next intersection point of $L$ with an arc in the anticlockwise direction. In the picture, this intersection is with the head of $\rho_{23}$. But in the polygon, it's with the head of $\rho_{24}$. Ergo, the picture and the polygon don't portray the same configuration... (cont'd)

Comment: ... To put it more plainly, in the picture, $\rho_{23}$ crosses $\rho_{24}$, but it doesn't in the polygon.

Comment: Okay thanks, maybe some curves must be switched, I suspected this. But, in any case,  how to explicitly draw the cyan curve in the polygon so that it passes  through the wall $\alpha_3$ (or $\beta_3$) and intersects only one of the curves on the right half (namely, $\tau_{23}$)? I always see intersections with at least two curves on the right.

Comment: I am pretty confident that, up to switching some colors in order to follow your remark, the curves in the polygon are the correct ones. But, also taking into consideration the possibile switchings, I am unable to draw the polygon model of the cyan curve. In the model, I always see too many intersections.

Comment: It's more than just switching some labels. In your perspective picture, there are curves that cross which don't cross in the polygon. Until you correct this mistake, you won't be able to get any intuition about what should happen on the polygon by looking at the perspective picture.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my drawing is bad (or I am missing something). What curves cross that do not cross in the polygon?

Comment: I mean, in both models, all the curves in the left cross only in $P_1$. And the curves in the right only in $P_2$.

Comment: The curves $\rho_{23}$ and $\rho_{24}$ cross twice in the picture -- once at $P_2$ and once behind the surface. It may be that, after isotoping $\rho_{23}$ over a bigon *and* switching some labels, the two pictures match. (And the same on the other side.)

Comment: Ok, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, your picture is not entirely accurate. But perhaps this is what you're looking for?

[image]

(Note that, if you had chosen a different gluing pattern for your once-punctured genus-two surface on the right, then the curve could have been drawn much more simply.)

Comment: Oh, this looks promising. For some reason, I overlooked this solution (maybe because my picture was not completely accurate, as you said). Thanks!